# Proper way to send FCM device token to a webview

Tags: react-native, webview, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a webapp built on Laravel that is to be displayed on a mobile app (both android and ios, which are being built using React Native) via WebView.

I managed to use evollu/react-native-fcm to generate the token.

My question is: what is the proper way to send this token to the WebView, so my webapp can relate it to a user and store it on the database?

My first idea was to pass it along to the URL being called by the WebView as a GET parameter, but the parameter always come blank on the other side, probably because the token is requested asynchronously and when the webview is called it didn't come yet.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to delay the rendering until the token was ready by using an if on the render method that would not return the webview if a state "loading" is true; then in the function that gets the token I used setState to change the value of loading to false.

Answer (score 0):

Either as a url parameter or via `postMessage`. In both ways you have to wait until the token is available. So load the page or render the webview when the token is available. Or you pass the token via `postMessage` immediately after the token was received.

The `postMessage` method is the recommended way, because you can load the page and wait for the token at the same time.

Comment: How could I delay the render method to wait for until the token is available?